# logistic regression - complete/quasi-separation

Tags: r, regression, logistic, separation

What is the implication if I don't fix a logistic regression that has complete or quasi separation? can I still read the marginal effects or are they not going to be valid?

My exercise is actually to just find out which independent variables are most predictive of Y.

I read some responses to complete/quasi-separation and I tried using logistf package for R but got this error message "NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call logistf". why does this arises?